# What is the difference and relation between Host Name and Canonical Name?

Tags: ip, domain-name

What is Canonical Name in relation to Host Name, Domain Name? Are they all pointing to the same IP?

Answer (score 8):

In DNS, a hostname is a domain name that identifies a host computer (e.g. foo.example.com). The term hostname is also used to mean the name used for a computer without the domain suffix (foo).

Note that the above usage, as used by DNS administrators, is slightly different from more causal usage where example.com would be considered a domain but many people don't realise a fully qualified hostname is also technically a domain name (see RFCs).

In DNS there are many types of records:

- "A" records associate a domain name with an address
- "CNAME" records associate an alias (extra) domain name with a canonical domain name

  - multiple CNAME records can be used to associate several aliases with a
    single canonical domain name
- "PTR" records are normally used to associate an IP-address with a canonical domain name.
- etc

"[Canonical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical)" means "unique distinguished exemplar". A computer may have many aliases but should only have one canonical name.

---

From [RFC1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt)

> CNAME           A <domain-name> which specifies the canonical or
>   primary
>                   name for the owner.  The owner name is an alias.

---

From [RFC1034](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt)

> Most of these systems have a notion that one of the equivalent set of
>   names is the canonical or primary name and all others are aliases.

Answer (score 5):

The **host name** is the real name the server has. A **canonical name** is a name that the host is known by, but that the host is not actually called.

A machine's host name could be "barkley.example.com", but because it runs the web and FTP services for the domain "example.com", it could have canonical names of "www.example.com" and "ftp.example.com".

Comment: so, canonical names are a subset of the single host name. Is it used for TCP protocol to direct the packets to a certain port(HTTP vs. FTP  for example)?

Comment: No. The name has nothing to do with which ports are available except where the server software itself restricts it (if even possible).

Comment: since different canonical name points to the same IP, why do we need more names other than the domain name?

Comment: For convenience and convention. Plus, it allows for moving services to a different host without having to change the name.

Comment: But multiple canonical names can point to the same host with a single IP. I do not understand what you mean by "moving services to a different host without having to change the name"?

Comment: They can be pointing to the same machine one day, and different machines the next. Nothing needs to be done to clients in order to make this migration work.

Comment: host name could be "barkley", Domain Name - "barkley.example.com", Canonical Name - any in any domain, but linked (in DNS) to Domain Name.

Comment: To be clear, CNAME records point aliases at the canonical name. So in Ignacio's answer, barkley.example.com is the canonical name, and www.example.com is an alias, and it's written as `www.example.com CNAME barkley.example.com` and barkley.example.com would have a record specifying its IP address, whereeas www.example.com wouldn't.

Comment: Now I am completely confused. Can it be that you are confusing an "alias" and a "canonical host name" here? To my understanding, a machine can only have a single canonical hostname.
In any case, this reply is directly contradictory to what RedGrittyBick says in his reply. Can

Answer (score 0):

Think of Robert Edward Lee. That's his full name, however, he is more commonly know him as:

- Robert E. Lee or
- Bobby Lee.

They are aliases. Or CNAMES. If you write to "Bobby Lee" instead of his full name, your letter will reach him, because the post office system will know how to route the letters to him.   All the letters will be sent to Arlington, Virginia.

The records in the post office system will indicate the following:

- Type=A, Name=Robert Edward Lee, Value=Arlington, Virginia
- Type=CNAME, Name=Bobby Lee, Value=Robert Edward Lee
- Type=CNAME, Name=Robert E. Lee, Value=Robert Edward Lee

Domain names. You can think of this as equivalent to "Lee". There are many people in the Lee family. You might address a letter to: "curtis.lee" for example. The post master general will ask someone in the Lee family, hey: "what is the address of curtis?", and they will tell you the final address of Curtis.

I know I used an analogy here - and yes there are problems with it - analogies are not perfect - but if I started with a technical definition of DNS Resource Records and referred you to RFC 1034 and RFC 1035, started talking about hostnames and how they are different to domain names - we'd take all day and night. This is a junk food definition, quick, greasy, cheap and dirty, but hopefully it is good enough to get you going. Read a formal definition with the above analogy in mind, and it should (hopefully) help you.